# prove an O(n) algorithm exists for 10 swaps

Tags: algorithm, sorting, swap

A famous problem is finding the minimum amount of swaps for sorting an array.  My problem is that we have array of size n and we know we can sort it with 10 swaps(we don't know the moves, only the number of the moves). I want to prove that There exists an O(n) algorithm (for time) that sorts this array.

First of all, for proving this statements should I present some code? I don't know how to prove it
And Second of all, is this related to minimum amount of swaps for sorting an array?

Thanks for your help

Comment: O(n) in what? Your premise already says there exists an algorithm that sorts the array in 10 swaps. The algorithm has to be O(n) in number of comparisons, I guess? Are there memory constraints?

Comment: @trentcl O(n) is for time.I forgot to mention it. There are no memory constraints

Comment: Hint: Timsort will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is in [Adaptive sorts algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort).

> A classic example of an adaptive sorting algorithm is **Straight Insertion Sort**. In this sorting algorithm, we scan the input from left to right, repeatedly finding the position of the current item, and insert it into an array of previously sorted items.

We know that:

> The performance of this algorithm can be described in terms of the number of inversions in the input, and then `T(n)` will be roughly equal to `I(A)+(n-1)`, where `I(A)` is the number of Inversions.

So, as in your case, the number of inversions is constant, the complexity of this algorithm will be `Theta(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

If we know that 10 swaps is enough for sorting an array then this array is nearly sorted with maximum 10*2 = 20 elements out of order. So if we find some sort algorithm that has O(n) on nearly sorted arrays then it is enough for proving your statement.

For example we can use 2 step solution:

1. find all out of order elements in array, remove and save them
2. insert saved elements in resulting array in right positions

With such “naive” algorithm it will take one pass for first step and 20 or less passes (20 out of order elements) for second step in worst case. So if `n >> 10` than it gets O(n) for you case. This proof is correct for any constant number of swaps if it doesn’t depend on `n`

Comment: How would you define an "out of order" element, and what O(n) algorithm do you propose to detect such elements?

Comment: @MarkDickinson “out of order” element can be found as part of sequence of array elements that isn’t ordered as needed. When we meet new element that is less than previous we knew that this or previous element is out of order. And may be some others near. As long as there are no more than 20 such elements it isn’t hard to check backward and forward to find borders of such wrong sequence. Even if we take several more elements than it is needed (for example all 20 neighbors for each occurrence) it doesn’t change O complexity.